# Renewal Date Calculation

Tags: php

I have an app where dates for subscriptions are stored. The dates don't need to be updated and preferred not. **I just need to calculate the next renewal date in the current year and beyond (future upcoming).** What I have works for previous month or year subs but not beyond that. I'm not sure how to go about it. Term 1: one time, 2: daily, 3: monthly, 4: yearly. Cycle is * term. So cycle 2 for term 3 is every 2 months.

```
        $id = $expense->id;
        $type = $expense->type;
        $term = $expense->term;
        $cycle = $expense->cycle;
        $usd = $expense->usd;
        $amount = $expense->amount;
        $date = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($expense->date));
        $date_day = date('d', strtotime($date));
        $date_month = date('m', strtotime($date));
        $date_year = date('Y', strtotime($date));

        if ( $expense->usd == 1 )
            $amount = $amount * 1.4;
        else
            $amount = $amount;

        if ( $expense->term == 2 ) {
            $renewal = date('Y/m/d');
        }
        else if ( $expense->term == 3 )
        {
            $amount = $amount / ( (365/12) * $cycle);

            $month = date('m') + $cycle;

            $renewal = date($date_year . '/' . $month . '/' . $date_day);
        }
        else if ( $expense->term == 4 )
        {
            $amount = $amount / (365 * $cycle);
            
            $year = date('Y') + $cycle;

            $renewal = date($year . '/' . $date_month . '/' . $date_day);
        }
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I only focused on how to calculate the next renewal date.

I used the `DateInterval` to add an interval to the subscription date.
Have a look at: https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.dateinterval.php
This should get you started, below you will find 4 examples.

```
<?php

// date interval periods
$terms = [
    1 => null, // do nothing
    2 => 'P1D', // daily
    3 => 'P1M', // monthly
    4 => 'P1Y', // yearly
];

// example data
$exampleSubscriptionDates = [
    [
        'subscriptionDate' => '1983-12-17',
        'term' => 1,
    ],
    [
        'subscriptionDate' => '2012-10-22',
        'term' => 2,
    ],
    [
        'subscriptionDate' => '2018-01-31',
        'term' => 3,
    ],
    [
        'subscriptionDate' => '2011-03-03',
        'term' => 4,
    ],
];

// foreach registration date calculate next renewal date
foreach ($exampleSubscriptionDates as $subscriptionInfo) {
    $subscriptionDate = new DateTimeImmutable($subscriptionInfo['subscriptionDate']);
    $currentDate = new DateTimeImmutable('now');

    // replace the part of the subscription date that isn't relevant for renewal if needed
    switch ($subscriptionInfo['term']) {
        case 1:
            $renewalDate = 'NONE';
            break;

        case 2:
            // daily subscription
            $renewalDate = $currentDate->format('Y/m/d');
            break;

        case 3:
            // monthly subscription, replace year and month with current year and month
            $newRenewalDate = $subscriptionDate->setDate(
                $currentDate->format('Y'),
                $currentDate->format('m'),
                $subscriptionDate->format('d')
            );

            // now add interval to the current renewal date only if our current day of month is higher
            if ($currentDate->format('d') > $newRenewalDate->format('d')) {
                $newRenewalDate = $newRenewalDate->add(new DateInterval($terms[$subscriptionInfo['term']]));
            }

            // adjust date if the day of the month doesn't exist in the current month
            if ($subscriptionDate->format('d') !== $newRenewalDate->format('d')) {
                $newRenewalDate = $newRenewalDate->modify('last day of previous month');
            }

            $renewalDate = $newRenewalDate->format('Y/m/d');
            break;

        case 4:
            // yearly subscription, replace year
            $newRenewalDate = $subscriptionDate->setDate(
                $currentDate->format('Y'),
                $subscriptionDate->format('m'),
                $subscriptionDate->format('d')
            );

            // now add interval to the current renewal date only if above calculated date is in the past
            if ($currentDate > $newRenewalDate) {
                $newRenewalDate = $newRenewalDate->add(new DateInterval($terms[$subscriptionInfo['term']]));
            }

            $renewalDate = $renewalDate = $newRenewalDate->format('Y/m/d');
            break;
    }

    echo 'Original subscription date: '.$subscriptionInfo['subscriptionDate'].' term: '.$subscriptionInfo['term'].' next subscription date: '.$renewalDate.PHP_EOL;
}
```

Comment: 2020/11/26 is being interpreted as 2021/01/26 not 2020/12/26

Comment: If you are using 2020/11/26 as your input date you can do this: 
$dateTime =  DateTime::createFromFormat('Y/m/d', '2020/11/26');
echo $dateTime->format('Y-m-d');

You should see the correct date.

Do you have an example

Comment: I added if ($current_date > $new_renewal_date) { to the add interval statements that were missing it and it fixed from the looks of it was that correct of me to add?

Comment: In theory that should not be needed. But you need to check your $currentDate value and the subscription date you are comparing it to. If you still need some help, create a phpfiddle with your current code and I'll have a look

Comment: $currentDate and $subscriptionDate are the same as your code, I only renamed the variables. I tested with some dates and 2020/11/26 was one that showed up as 2021/01/26 this would be for term 3

Comment: I updated the response. It was missing a day of the month check!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/225385/discussion-between-cecil-zorg-and-whisky).